# Displaying and retrieving 'seconds' with TimePicker

Tags: java, android

Currently the TimePicker view shows only hours and minutes by default and I am retrieving the values using `getCurrentHour()` and `getCurrentMinute()`.

Is there a solution to add seconds to the TimePicker view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write your own widget for that, AFAIK.